# Update trigger firing after insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I created an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on the table `DEP_MARCHE` that will insert  two rows into my audit table `AuditDepMarche`: one row for the old values (from the virtual table `DELETED`) and the second contains the new values (from the virtual table `INSERTED`) of all columns of `DEP_MARCHE` (`DEP_MARCHE` and `AuditDepMarche` have the same structure). Also I created an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that adds one row to my audit table.

The problem is that when I insert something into `DEP_MARCHE` the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger is fired, consequently three rows are added to my audit table (one row added by the `AFTER INSERT` trigger and the two others by the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger )

I searched in the internet, the solution I found is: to create one trigger for both (`AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`) and test on the virtual table `DELETED` if it's empty then I run the queries for after Insert trigger, else I run the queries of after update trigger, something like this (it didn't work for me though) :

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_AlteredRecord 
ON [dbo].[Foo]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DelCount int;
    DECLARE @InsCount int;

    SELECT @InsCount = COUNT(Col1) FROM INSERTED;
    SELECT @DelCount = COUNT(Col1) FROM DELETED;

    IF @InsCount > 0 AND @DelCount = 0
    BEGIN
        -- At least 1 row inserted. Your Insert Trigger logic here
    END
    ELSE IF @DelCount > 0 AND @InsCount > 0
    BEGIN
        -- old row deleted, new row inserted; both indicates an update.
        -- your update logic here.  
    END
END
```

After I implemented this logic to my code, it began to add not 3 rows, but 5 rows into my audit table whenever I insert something into the `DEP_MARCHE` table (One row for by insert trigger, and two rows; old & new values, duplicated => 4 rows )

This is my code, I would appreciate any help

```
Drop trigger if exists DepMarcheAudit_UPDATE_INSERT
go
CREATE TRIGGER DepMarcheAudit_UPDATE_INSERT
ON DEP_MARCHE
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN

   Declare @DelCount int;
   Declare @InsCount int;

   SELECT @InsCount = Count(*) FROM INSERTED;
   SELECT @DelCount = Count(*) FROM DELETED;

 -----------AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER TRANSACTIONS---------
IF @InsCount > 0 AND @DelCount > 0
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @AUDIT_OPERATION_OLD VARCHAR(50)
   SET @AUDIT_OPERATION_OLD = 'mise à jour (Old values)'

   DECLARE @AUDIT_OPERATION_NEW VARCHAR(50)
   SET @AUDIT_OPERATION_NEW = 'mise à jour (New values)'

   declare @StartTime datetimeoffset(7) = sysdatetimeoffset();

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[DepMarcheAudit](
   [CODE_MARCHE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_TYPE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_DATE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_TIME]
   ,[AUDIT_ID_USER]
         ,[LIBELLE_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_FOURNISSEUR]
         ,[NUMERO_MARCHE]
         ,[OBSERVATION_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_NATURE]
         ,[CODE_AO]
         ,[DOC_CONTRAT]
         ,[IS_DEPENSE_SIMPLIFIEE],
         [startTime]
         )
   SELECT 
   [CODE_MARCHE]
   ,@AUDIT_OPERATION_OLD
   ,GETDATE()
   ,(CONVERT([time],getdate(),0))
   ,HOST_NAME()
         ,[LIBELLE_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_FOURNISSEUR]
         ,[NUMERO_MARCHE]
         ,[OBSERVATION_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_NATURE]
         ,[CODE_AO]
         ,[DOC_CONTRAT]
         ,[IS_DEPENSE_SIMPLIFIEE]
         ,@StartTime
   FROM DELETED; 

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[DepMarcheAudit](
   [CODE_MARCHE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_TYPE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_DATE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_TIME]
   ,[AUDIT_ID_USER]
         ,[LIBELLE_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_FOURNISSEUR]
         ,[NUMERO_MARCHE]
         ,[OBSERVATION_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_NATURE]
         ,[CODE_AO]
         ,[DOC_CONTRAT]
         ,[IS_DEPENSE_SIMPLIFIEE]
         ,[startTime]
         )



   SELECT 



   [CODE_MARCHE]
   ,@AUDIT_OPERATION_NEW
   ,getdate()
   ,(CONVERT([time],getdate(),0))
   ,HOST_NAME()
         ,[LIBELLE_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_FOURNISSEUR]
         ,[NUMERO_MARCHE]
         ,[OBSERVATION_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_NATURE]
         ,[CODE_AO]
         ,[DOC_CONTRAT]
         ,[IS_DEPENSE_SIMPLIFIEE]
         ,@StartTime
   FROM INSERTED;
   END

--------------------AFTER INSERT TRIGGER TRANSACTION-----------------------------
ELSE IF @InsCount > 0 AND @DelCount = 0
   
   BEGIN
   
   DECLARE @AUDIT_OPERATION VARCHAR(50)
   SET @AUDIT_OPERATION = 'Insertion'
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[DepMarcheAudit](
   [CODE_MARCHE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_TYPE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_DATE]
   ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_TIME]
   ,[AUDIT_ID_USER]
         ,[LIBELLE_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_FOURNISSEUR]
         ,[NUMERO_MARCHE]
         ,[OBSERVATION_MARCHE]
         ,[CODE_NATURE]
         ,[CODE_AO]
         ,[DOC_CONTRAT]
         ,[IS_DEPENSE_SIMPLIFIEE]
         ,[startTime])

         SELECT 

   [CODE_MARCHE]
   ,@AUDIT_OPERATION
   ,GETDATE()
   ,(CONVERT([time],getdate(),0))
   ,HOST_NAME()
   ,[LIBELLE_MARCHE]
   ,[CODE_FOURNISSEUR]
   ,[NUMERO_MARCHE]
   ,[OBSERVATION_MARCHE]
   ,[CODE_NATURE]
   ,[CODE_AO]
   ,[DOC_CONTRAT]
   ,[IS_DEPENSE_SIMPLIFIEE]
   , sysdatetimeoffset()
FROM INSERTED; 

END
END
GO
```

Comment: If you need different logic for an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` you are better off creating separate triggers.

Comment: Do as Larnu recommends. Separate the two triggers, one for AFTER INSERT and the other for AFTER UPDATE. This will simplify things for you as well as keep it manageable for anyone going in after the fact to make adjustments.

Comment: Don't forget to add a SET NOCOUNT ON.

Comment: Did you have both a insert trigger and a trigger for insert & update?  I don't see how else you are getting both firing.

Comment: @Larnu at the beginning I had created separate triggers, and then Ihad also the problem: the update trigger was always fired after an insert

Comment: @RandyinMarin No I don't have a trigger for insert and a trigger for insert & update, once I created the insert & update Trigger I dropped the insert trigger and the update trigger too

Comment: Without two triggers, I don't see how you got 3 records for 1 operation.

Comment: @assia an `INSERT` **only** trigger will never fire on an `UPDATE`.

Comment: @assia, do a refresh on the table in SSMS and insure the triggers expected are present.  The trigger will fire as a result of a single insert, update, or delete query.  For an insert, only triggers for insert fire.  If you have another trigger that does an update to the same table, then let us know because it get's more complicated if there is direct or indirect recursion.

Comment: @RandyinMarin I will create a new simple table and an audit table too, then I ll create a new update & insert trigger, do an insert and see what happens, this way I ll be sure if the problem is coming from redundant triggers (even though I couldn't find any) or not.

Comment: @RandyinMarin and I ll let you know the result for sure

Answer (score 1):

You can use one trigger for inserts, updates, and deletes because you are doing the same thing for all. The only difference appears to be a message about it being an insert, update(before), update(after), or a delete. I don't see a delete, but I included it because it's no additional work.

If it's a delete, the select from INSERTED will insert nothing into the audit table. If it's an insert, the select from DELETED will insert nothing into the audit table. If it's an update, both inserts will insert into the audit table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DepMarcheAudit_UPDATE_INSERT_DELETE
ON DEP_MARCHE
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @DelCount int;
    DECLARE @InsCount int;

    SELECT @InsCount = Count(*) FROM INSERTED;
    SELECT @DelCount = Count(*) FROM DELETED;

    IF @InsCount = 0 AND @DelCount = 0 RETURN

    DECLARE @AUDIT_OPERATION_OLD VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @AUDIT_OPERATION_NEW VARCHAR(50);

    IF @InsCount > 0 AND @DelCount > 0 
    BEGIN
       SET @AUDIT_OPERATION_OLD = 'Update (Old values)';
       SET @AUDIT_OPERATION_NEW = 'Update (New values)';
    END
    ELSE IF @InsCount > 0
    BEGIN
       SET @AUDIT_OPERATION_OLD = NULL;
       SET @AUDIT_OPERATION_NEW = 'Insert (New values)';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       SET @AUDIT_OPERATION_OLD = 'Delete (Old values)';
       SET @AUDIT_OPERATION_NEW = NULL;
    END;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DepMarcheAudit](
       [CODE_MARCHE]
       ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_TYPE]
       ...
       )
    SELECT 
       [CODE_MARCHE]
       ,@AUDIT_OPERATION_OLD
       ...
    FROM DELETED; 

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DepMarcheAudit](
       [CODE_MARCHE]
       ,[AUDIT_OPERATION_TYPE]
       ...
       )
    SELECT 
       [CODE_MARCHE]
       ,@AUDIT_OPERATION_NEW
       ...
    FROM INSERTED; 

    RETURN;

END
```

Do remember to delete or disable the other triggers if they are redundant.